# Issue with Python extract input from csv and create wordpress post

Tags: python, wordpress, csv, xml-rpc

I'm stuck on a problem.

I'm trying to get my script to read this particular set of data from a csv file without the ' " ', and create a wordpress post through wordpress_xmlrpc.

So my set of data in the 1.csv is something like

`" ['1', '2','3'] ","['2','3','4']"

If I open and read it with the following code, i am able to read the data without ' " '

```
with open('1.csv','r') as f:
    csv1 = csv.reader(f)
    for column in csv1:
    print(column[0])
```

it'll print out the way i wanted it to

```
['1','2','3']
```

however for some reason if I read it say through WordpressPost

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import GetUserInfo
post = WordPressPost()
        post.terms_names = {
          'post_tag': column[0],
        }
        print(post.terms_names)
```

it'll print out as

```
" ['1', '2','3'] "
```

I'm a bit clueless here atm as even if I call

```
print(post.terms_names.replace('"',''))
```

it'll still ignore it and print

```
" ['1', '2','3'] "
```

Answer (score 0):

sorted.
Figured out that ast.literal_eval would solve the issue.